# gtksourceview-sharp help

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

Is there any quick tutorial on the net on how to get started with using gtksourceview-sharp? I have gtksourceview-sharp.dll but I can't get it to work, even when I have the libgtksourceview-1.0-0.dll in the same directory with it... Thanks!

Comment: Since DLL-loading can be platform specific, more information is needed:
 - What operating system?
 - What compiler/IDE?

Comment: Do you know any sample like program using the gtksourceview-sharp? I'm searching google but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

There is an example program in the source tree:
http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/gnome-desktop-sharp/sample/SourceViewTest.cs?revision=94548&view=markup

(Found using google code search, a useful way to look for examples)